# Trying to find a touchscreen that will be compatible with a microcontroller

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, touchscreen

I was wondering id anyone knows or have experience with building something that is controlled by a touch screen? I want a 3x3inches touch screen , that will be controlled by an "fairly-easy" to program micro-controller, maybe Arduino?. Where to buy it and what do you guys suggest? etc. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.liquidware.com/shop/show/TSL/TouchShield+Slide

Comment: Have a look at this mannufacturer http://www.lcd-module.com  Mouser carries their LCDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square touchscreen displays are not common; search for **4.3" touchscreens** to obtain approximately the same screen area, typically in a rectangular 4:3 or widescreen format.

If you are not experienced in microcontroller programming, a **serial** touchscreen (SPI or I2C connection) would be easier to use than one designed for parallel data.

Also, touchscreen and LCD display panels often communicate via a flexible plastic connector, which is not trivial to connect up if you are not experienced at soldering small pitch connectors.

More suitable to your purposes would thus be a serial touchscreen module that comes pre-fitted on a PCB with standard 0.1" pin-out connectors. For instance, the $38 [iTead ITDB02-4.3](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/display/tft-lcm/im120419007.html), a 4.3" color LCD plus touchscreen, which also contains an SD card socket that might find use in your project. (*This is not a recommendation, merely an example product*)

Arduino programming support for this module is available through the [UTFT Library](http://henningkarlsen.com/electronics/library.php?id=51), saving some effort in just getting the device to work. The same library also works with a variety of other touchscreen and LCD devices, so changing to a different device in the future is an option.

For even simpler connectivity, look for an Arduino compatible [touchscreen shield](http://www.codevision.be/arduino-shields/4-3-lcd-b-arduino-shield). These shields just plug right onto the Arduino board, so no fiddling about with jumpers or getting things wrong. Of course, there is a price premium for the convenience: EUR95 for this example. Cheaper ones do exist, with varying levels of library support and performance.

If you look at smaller touchscreens, or go with monochrome, the price drops significantly. There are often monochrome serial touchscreen modules on eBay for really low prices. Watch out for the connector the device uses, though. FPC would require that additional step of soldering up a very small pitch connector, typically 0.8 mm pitch with up to a dozen traces to be soldered.

Sites like [Adafruit](http://adafruit.com/) and [SparkFun](http://www.sparkfun.com/) may also be worth a browse, not the least because they cater to the hobbyist community, so devices sold there are supported by an active community reporting successes or problems. This in itself might be the biggest help in getting your touchscreen project up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Arduino.  Adadfruit has a [2.8" touchscreen shield](http://www.adafruit.com/products/376), which I have purchased from them for $59.  It is currently out of stock, but should be available again in a week or so.  Maker SHED [has the same item](http://www.makershed.com/2_8_TFT_Touch_Shield_For_Arduino_p/mkad36.htm), but they are also out of stock.

SeeedStudio has a [2.8" touchscreen shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/28-tft-touch-shield-v20-p-1286.html?cPath=132_134) for $55 (V2.0), which appears to be similar but not identical to the Adafruit one.  The have also marked down their [original version V1.0 of the display](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/28-tft-touch-shield-p-864.html) to $35.